# Differential Equation Reduction of power

Tags: multivariable-calculus

$${d\over dt}{ dx\over dt} + {k\over m} x^{-3} =0$$. 
 Find $x$ where $k$ is constant $k>0$. 
Here i don't know how to solve this differential equation because of the power of x.

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Do you mean you can't solve $x''(t) = - {k \over m}x^{-3}$? If so, can you solve $x'(t) = a x^{-2}$?

Comment: yes i can solve that and that is what i mean

Answer (score 1):

You have

$$ x'' = -\frac{k}{m} x^{-3} $$

Multiply both sides by $x'$ and integrate

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
x' x'' &= -\frac{k}{m} \cdot \frac{x'}{x^{3}} \\
\implies \frac{1}{2} (x')^{2} &= \frac{k}{m} \cdot \frac{1}{2x^{2}} \\
\implies x' &= \pm \sqrt{\frac{k}{m}} \cdot \frac{1}{x}
\end{split}
\end{equation}

where in the second line, we have assumed the integration constant to be zero (as you have provided no conditions). This is a separable ODE

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\implies \int x dx &= \pm \sqrt{\frac{k}{m}} \int dt \\
\implies \frac{x^{2}}{2} &= \pm \sqrt{\frac{k}{m}} t + C_{1} \\
\implies x &= \pm \sqrt{\left( \pm 2 \sqrt{\frac{k}{m}} t + C_{2} \right)}
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Now check to see if the solutions satisfy the ODE.